# How to use Geo Location in every page in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am using GeoLocation NativeGeoCoder plugins in ionic for the getting. i want to use location in multiple pages.

i am creating function in `app.component.ts`

```
constructor(
    private geolocation: Geolocation,
    private nativegeocoder: NativeGeocoder
  ) {
    this.getGeoLocation();
  }

getGeoLocation() {
    const options: NativeGeocoderOptions = {
        useLocale: true,
        maxResults: 5
    };
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp);
        this.nativegeocoder.reverseGeocode(resp.coords.latitude, resp.coords.longitude, options)
        .then((result: NativeGeocoderResult[]) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result[0]));
        }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

how to use and call functio for refresh the location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You have to use `watchPosition`   instead of `getCurrentPosition`

**Please create service as given below** this service has one function and one subject to emit the updated location value through the app wherever we have subscribe that subject.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()

export class Location {
  private _Location = new Subject<any>();

  getGeoLocation() {
    this.geolocation.watchPosition().subscribe((position) => {
      this._Location.next(position)
      console.log(position);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
}
```

**In component ts file** You have to inject the service into constructor. and after that you can use getGeoLocation function to update the location and _Location to subscribe the updated location.

```js
constructor(private locate: Location){}

ngOnInit() {
  // below code to take the updated snapshot of location
  this.locate.getGeoLocation()

  // below code to subscribe the updated location
  this.locate._Location.subscribe(location => {
    console.log(location);
  })
}
```